# Extract data from External XML file using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using given below code in XSL file Both xsl and Results.xml are at same location but it cant give output.actually i want to access nodes of Results.xml file to extract data.

```
<xsl:variable name="fi" select="document('Results.xml')"/>
            <b><xsl:value-of select="$fi/Report/Doc/DName"/></b>
```

Comment: What XSLT processor, and how are you loading the stylesheet?  There can be issues resolving relative URIs in the `document` function if the processor doesn't know the URI of the stylesheet (for example if you're loading it from an `InputStream` rather than a `File` in Java).

Answer (score 2):

**When the below XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="fi" select="document('Results.xml')"/>  
            <b><xsl:value-of select="$fi/Report/Doc/DName"/></b>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**transforms below XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>    
<Report>
    <Doc>
        <DName>Sample</DName>
    </Doc>
</Report>
```

**gives the required output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<b>Sample</b>
```